# Questions about exporting report to Excel

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, export-to-excel

I'm using SSRS 2008, I have a table report which includes a Region column that all other columns are grouped by it.

I needed the report to be divided in different excel sheets when exporting it, which I have already done.

I also needed to not include the region column in the report itself, so I hide it.

But when exporting it to Excel I get Column A as a blank column that the user needs to delete.

So I have the following questions:

1. How can I exclude a column from a report but still keeping it as a group and breaking the report by it?
2. How can I get the names of each sheet to display the names of the Regions?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answers:

1. I deleted the column but kept the Group when the question was prompt to me.
2. On tablix member properties (when clicking on the relevant group) there is "Group" > "Page Name" > expression > =Fields!Region.Value.

It works great!